# Drawing partial circle arc in 2D

Tags: vb.net, winforms, powerpacks

I'm trying to draw a partial circle arc in Visual Basic. (Example: 75% of an outer arc.)

I tried to do this both by adding in the Visual Power Packs and by using the below code but I can't seem to figure out how to hide a portion of the arc without either covering everything within the circle or disabling the circle altogether.

[image]

(The goal being that as the countdown timer ticks down, a portion of the circle disappears as the clock is counting down. So at 0:15, there's half the circle and the like.)

Is there a way to draw a 2D circle arc that doesn't involve using any sort of graphics engine?

Comment: We have no context (where is that snippet?) but `CreateGraphics` is almost always the wrong thing to do.  Whatever you draw doesnt persist.  You should also be disposing of the pen.

Comment: Ah fair enough, I'll remove the snippet. I normally just draw the circles with the PowerPacks off the toolbar. I found that code and figured it would be helpful to the solution.

Comment: I am pretty sure there are several such animals on CodeProject